# Invalid usage of a function $FBObjectName()

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am using suagr crm  7.6, 
i made a package and installing it to on demand.
But it is giving me error `Invalid usage of a function`

I search on google and found this:

```
class myclass {
    static function say_hello()
    {
        echo "Hello!\n";
    }
}

$classname = "myclass";

call_user_func(array($classname, 'say_hello'));
call_user_func($classname .'::say_hello'); // As of 5.2.3

$myobject = new myclass();

call_user_func(array($myobject, 'say_hello'));
```

But it is not solving my problem.my code is like this:

```
$FBObjectName = "{$bean->object_name}FormBase";
$formBase = new $FBObjectName();
```

And it is giving me a error invalid use of function is there any other way for it please explain me and help me.

I get same error for this code :

```
$action = "display_" . strtolower($this->cal->view);
return $this->$action();
```

I solve its like this:

```
return call_user_func(array($this, $action));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Module Loader restrictions](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.6/API/Application/Module_Loader/Module_Loader_Restrictions/).

Neither variable classes nor variable functions nor call_user_func() are permitted.  You will need to either move your client from Sugar's On-Demand servers or rewrite your solution.

Comment: rewrite your solution means ? i did not understand.

Comment: If your code will not pass Sugar's package scanner then you will need to change your code.  I'm not really sure what you're trying to do so I can't help you with that.